# Must Zabbix proxy have its own static IP?

Tags: zabbix

I'm currently building a monitoring system with Zabbix. I'm especially trying to set up a Zabbix proxy and

As far as I know, if I set the Zabbix proxy as active, it's then not necessary for the Zabbix server to have a connection with the Zabbix proxy.

Now, what I wonder is if each Zabbix proxy must have its own static IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the proxy is set to active, there is no need for them to have static IP addresses - all that is needed is a TCP connection to the server.